# Unstage only new files using Git

Tags: git

I've accidentally staged a lot of changes including new files that I do not want to commit.

How can I unstage or reset only the new files?

*I am not looking for a script of any kind; I am looking for core git functionality to be exposed and documented here on SO under a meaningful topic title.*

Answer (score 9):

One way you may be able to do this is to unstage / reset everything and then re-stage only what you wanted:

```
git reset HEAD ./
git add -u
# -u stages changes to tracked files, and will not stage new files.
```

Comment: That's pretty much the way.  Note that this is a `reset --mixed` and can be spelled `git reset --mixed HEAD -- .`, which makes explicit that you're asking to move `HEAD` to `HEAD` with a path-name of `.`.  Moving `HEAD` to `HEAD` is itself a no-op, so only the index-reset part (via `--mixed`) has any effect, and the path specified is `.`, the current directory (all its files, and any sub-directories and their files, recursively).

Comment: Note: Prior to the initial commit, there isn't a `HEAD` to `reset` to. In that case, `git rm --cached -r .` will unstage everything.